# Login to website and download csv using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to export csv files from finviz.com. I can manually login via browser and export it but it doesn't work programmatically. Here is my code:

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://www.finviz.com/login_submit.ashx'
file_url = 'https://elite.finviz.com/export.ashx?v=152&c=1,,65,66,67,25,64,63,49'

payload = {
    'email': 'email@gmail.com',
    'password': 'myPassword',
    'remember': 'true'}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(login_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response = s.get(file_url)
    if response.ok:
        with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
    else:
        print(f'Failed to download the file: status code {response.status_code}')
```

Note that if I get the headers directly from the browser after authentication and use that in the code, it works. So the code below works but I have to keep generating new cookies every time it expires.

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://www.finviz.com/login_submit.ashx'
file_url = 'https://elite.finviz.com/export.ashx?v=152&c=1,,65,66,67,25,64,63,49'

payload = {
    'email': 'email@gmail.com',
    'password': 'myPassword',
    'remember': 'true'}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.google-analytics.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '<long_cookie_string>',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://elite.finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&c=1,,65,66,67,25,64,63,49',
    'Origin': 'https://elite.finviz.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://elite.finviz.com',
    'referer': 'https://elite.finviz.com/',
    'content-length': '0',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers)
    if response.ok:
        with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
    else:
        print(f'Failed to download the file: status code {response.status_code}')
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use Python to create a session and manage cookies?

Comment: I believe as the first step in the session, you need to GET the login page, so the server has a chance to send the cookies.  If you just jump right in with a POST, the server hasn't had a chance to establish the cookies.

Comment: I tried `s.get(login_url)` before the post but it did not work.

Comment: What happens when you submit your GET to the `file_url`? (e.g. do you get a non-200 status code? any errors?)

Comment: Still get 200 status code when I submit GET to `file_url`. File is not downloaded and there are no other errors.